# How to create a dataframe depending on 2 others existing dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 like this:

```
topic_id    topic   
1           Sun
2           Cloud
3           Rain
```

I have an other dataframe df2 that looks like this:

```
article_id  title    topics
    1       title_1  []
    2       title_2  [Sun, Cloud]
    3       title_3  [Rain]
```

My goal is to use df1 and df2 to create a dataframe df3.

I want to create a row in df3 everytime a topic in lists of topics column appears.
And in this row I would like to have the article id of df2 when a topic appears and also the topic id of df1. If the list is empty nothing is created in df3.

I would like to have a new dataframe looking like this:

```
article_id  topic_id    topics
        2       1       Sun
        2       2       Cloud
        3       3       Rain
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: What is output if changed `[Rain]` to `[Wind]` ?

Comment: The output will be the same excepted the topic wind will have a different id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with default inner join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), last change order of columns by list:

```
cols = ['article_id','topic_id','topics']
df = df2.explode('topics').merge(df1.rename(columns={'topic':'topics'}))[cols]
print (df)
   article_id  topic_id topics
0           2         1    Sun
1           2         2  Cloud
2           3         3   Rain
```